# Get-ItemProperty : Cannot bind argument to parameter 'Path' because it is null

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0, powershell-remoting

I have read alot of the posts and have pulled alot of great info. But i am still having an issue getting a version number to pull from the registry. I found this code to get an IE version, and that seems to work just fine.

```
$array =@() 
$keyname = 'SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Internet Explorer' 
$computernames = Get-Content C:\scripts\test_names1.csv 
foreach ($server in $computernames) 
{ 
$reg = [Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey]::OpenRemoteBaseKey('LocalMachine', $server) 
$key = $reg.OpenSubkey($keyname) 
$value = $key.GetValue('svcVersion') 
 $obj = New-Object PSObject 

    $obj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "ComputerName" -Value $server 

    $obj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "IEVersion" -Value $value 

    $array += $obj  


} 

$array | select ComputerName,IEVersion | export-csv C:\scripts\test1-IE_Version.csv
```

But when i modify it to try to get a Google Chrome version it fails with the

```
**Get-ItemProperty : Cannot bind argument to parameter 'Path' because it is null.**
```

Here is what I modified to try to get the Chrome version.

```
$array =@()
$keyname = '\\SOFTWARE\\Wow6432Node\\Google\\Update\\clients\\{8A69D345-D564-463c-AFF1-A69D9E530F96}'
$computernames = Get-Content C:\scripts\test_names.csv
foreach ($server in $computernames)
{
$reg = [Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey]::OpenRemoteBaseKey('LocalMachine', $server)
$regkey = $reg.OpenSubKey('SOFTWARE\\Wow6432Node\\Google\\Update\\clients\\{8A69D345-D564-463c-AFF1-A69D9E530F96}')
$value = (Get-ItemProperty -Path $regkey -Name pv).pv
$obj = New-Object PSObject 

    $obj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "ComputerName" -Value $server 
    $obj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Installed" -Value $installed 
    $obj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "ChromeVersion" -Value $value
    $array += $obj  
}

$array | select ComputerName,Installed,ChromeVersion | export-csv C:\scripts\1222016_Chrome_Version.csv
```

I had to change the $keyname and $value variables due to the original edit throwing even more errors. I am completely new at powershell so be easy on me.

Thanks in advance.

-S

Comment: Would recommend `Import-Csv` over `Get-Content` for CSV files.

Comment: What debugging have you tried? Usually when you get an error due to a null value it's because something that you expect to exist does not exist.

Comment: When i step through it it dumps at the "You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
At C:\scripts\Get_Chrome_Version.ps1:8 char:1
+ $value = $regkey.GetValue('pv')"

Comment: Which I can see, the $regkey var doesn't look like it has a value.  When it runs it has one but when it goes to grab the var $regkey the $reg looks empty?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following works for me, which is basically the same as your IE code:

```
$keyname = 'SOFTWARE\\Wow6432Node\\Google\\Update\\clients\\{8A69D345-D564-463c-AFF1-A69D9E530F96}'
$reg = [Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey]::OpenRemoteBaseKey('LocalMachine', $server)
$regkey = $reg.OpenSubKey($keyname)
$value = $regkey.GetValue('pv')
```

Comment: I have to missing something else. I can get this to run locally,but as soon as i add try to get the remote information, i get the path is null.                      $regkey = 'HKLM:SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Google\Update\clients\{8A69D345-D564-463c-AFF1-A69D9E530F96}'
    $checkkey= Test-Path $regkey
    $regpath = $regkey
    if ($checkkey -eq $true) {(Get-ItemProperty -path $regpath -name pv).pv}
    ELSE {'Not Installed'}

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question, you are asking about how to tell what programs are installed on a computer, and also what the IE version is on a computer, which is a special case.

First, if an app is "installed" and appears in the `Programs and Features` list, then you can use the Get-InstalledApp.ps1 script I wrote from this article to see what applications are installed:

[Windows IT Pro: Auditing 32-Bit and 64-Bit Applications with PowerShell](http://windowsitpro.com/scripting/auditing-32-bit-and-64-bit-applications-powershell)

However, since Internet Explorer is an OS component and is not "installed" as a typical program, I wrote a different script to find the IE version:

[Get-IEVersion.ps1](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Get-IEVersionps1-44863ea8)

Comment: Technically I'm looking to retrieve the version of what is installed. I'm basically double checking our third party update installer.

Comment: Understood. The scripts in my answer will accomplish this.